# Java Spark and Database Connection Pooling

Tags: java, database, web, server

How i can configure Java Spark to use connection pooling for a database?
I know that Java Spark uses Jetty web server. But i am not sure about the process for connection pooling for database.

https://sparkjava.com/

Comment: Do you mean connection handler pooling / threading?
https://sparkjava.com/documentation#threadpool

Comment: Nope. This pooling/threads that you mention is for handling in parallel incoming request. I am care about database connection pooling.